# MySQL change base of a large number

Tags: mysql, sql, radix

I would like to change the base of a large number (72 bits) but I saw somewhere that `CONV` is limited to 64 bits. Indeed, when I do

```sql
SELECT CONV('05A2919F5812D0CD80', 16, 3);
```

MySQL gives `11112220022122120101211020120210210211220` but I expect `221122112211221122112211221122112211221122`

Comment: You saw that in the documentation:  "Otherwise, N is treated as unsigned. CONV() works with 64-bit precision":  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv.

Comment: What use would that number be to MySQL? You can't store it in `BIGINT`. You can't represent it as any normal integer, either. Could you work with this number as hex instead?

Comment: It's stored in a BINARY(9) column.